# How to get Facebook page notification via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Got a issue with Facebook Graph API. I want to read page notifications via Graph API. But Facebook documentation only states about user's notification.

Following only returns a user's notification (the user who provided the access token for this.)

http://graph.facebook.com/me/notifications

**I did following techniques. But no luck.**

**01.** But i tried with different urls with access token provided by the page. (with my stupid guess work by replacing page-id for me)

http://graph.facebook.com/page-id/notifications

**02.** Checked with Insights API. But Insights doesn't provide a straight forward solutions. This is more like stats. But all i just need a list of latest user/fan/post actions in the  page.

https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/insights/field

Some background about my App (hope no issues with this as other API's working),

- Platform .Net 4.0
- Library I am using is [C# Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk)

Facebook documentation doesn't help much. I have spent a few day on this to find a solution for this. Just wondering if any of you guys came across this issue and solved. I hope i didn't put a duplicate question here, as i did search for few days on Stackoverflow too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a page notification API. I don't believe there is any way to directly query this data.

You can get notifications of changes to a Facebook page using the Real-Time API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I did check on Real-Time API. At this point, to make our app to listen for subscription callback, would need significant change effort. its not feasible for us at the moment.

Comment: Your C# Facebook SDK rocks mate. Very cool and makes our life easy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook now allows you to read Page unread notifications by querying the edge: `{page-id}/notifications`.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/page/notifications

Comment: Where do you get the `page-id` from?

Comment: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
Get the Page Access token for the page you want and with `GET` selected, enter `me?fields=id,name` and click Submit. It should return you the numeric ID of the page. But as far as I have tried, alphanumeric ID also works. i.e. www.facebook.com/{alphanumeric_id}/

Comment: Is it possible to filter these notifications by a date range?

Answer (score 1):

From the FB Page docs for the notifications edge...

Notifications for this Page. **Deprecated April 30, 2019.**

Looks like the only way to track Page notifications at the moment is via the realtime Webhooks for a page, which isn't the same as reading the notifications from FB but it appears to be where we're at...until FB changes their mind again.  ;)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/realtime/