# FB Graph API: Detecting post publishing/editing on a public page

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, selenium

An Parliament member in Israel has just removed an embarrassing FB post ([you really don't want to know](http://www.talschneider.com/2014/01/15/tidbitsjan15/)).

I've tossed a little [Python+Selenium script](https://gist.github.com/adamatan/8434642) based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15870708/51197):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import datetime

filename = "miri_regev_"+datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d.%H:%M:%S")+".png"
fox = webdriver.Firefox()
fox.get('https://www.facebook.com/miri.regev.il')

fox.save_screenshot(filename) # saves screenshot of entire page
fox.quit()
```

However, running this script periodically is a waste of time and space. I would like to run it only when the FB publishes a new post or updates an existing one.

Is there a way to use FB Graph API to query for new posts on a public page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253523/how-to-get-facebook-page-notification-via-graph-api) to a similar question, you can get notifications of changes to a Facebook page using the Real-Time API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: Getting response via callback URL? Awesome.